Ubuntu 24.04/10
Has Ubuntu tested the Try and Install process with Gigabyte or MSI motherboards with latest bios recently? I've been trying to install 24.04 on new boards and it won't install. I get the Try and Install grub prompt via usb and after selecting install, the usb spins for 1 second and stops.
Just tried to install 24.04 on:
MSI B550-A Pro
(latest) BIOS E7C56AMS.AJ1 2024-08-27
and
Gigabyte B550MDS3H AC(rev.1.7)
(latest) BIOS FEd 9/2/2024
using:
AMD Ryzen 7 5700G
Vengeance 64G 3600MHz
The Gigabyte is a replacement board since the previous board, MSI, was doing the same thing on a new install to 24.04. Did an upgrade on the MSI, 24.04, on Oct 3, and Ubuntu never came back up. Tried reinstalling 24.04 and have been experiencing the same issue now on three different boards (I purchased and returned another board, thinking it was the board that was the issue).
AMD put out new drivers, please incorporate them into your Try and Install. I've been without my main machine now for almost a month.
I've even installed 24.04 on an old machine where everything still works. I even installed AMD's new driver set:
Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 24.20.3 for Ubuntu 24.04.1 HWE
Revision Number 24.20.3
File Size 14 KB
Release Date 2024-10-11
I transferred the newly installed disk to the MSI machine. When booting it gets as far as the grub prompt. Machine reboots 1 second after selecting Ubuntu at the prompt.
Installing 24.04 on a machine that works with new AMD driver set, doesn't work when transferring the drive to the MSI machine. The drivers need to be incorporated with the Try and install from Ubuntu so the install can happen from usb. Again, I've been trying different combinations of this since Oct 3. It's now Oct 28 and have made no progress.

Testing on a wide variety of hardware, and reporting the bugs found, is a community role. Please file bug reports when hardware does not work with Ubuntu.
